# Code Igniter form_validation load fatal error

Tags: codeigniter

I am using code igniter 2.0.3.

When I try loading form_validation in my controller $this->load->library('form_validation'), I get an error message:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function set_rules() on a non-object in D:\Installation\xampp\htdocs\MyApp\application\controllers\login.php on line 44

On line 44 in login.php, this is what I have:

> $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|required');

When I load form_validation in autoload.php, there are no errors.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

The only way I could reproduce that error was to flip-flop the position of `library` and the `validation`:

```
Causes Error -
$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('name', 'Name', 'trim|required');
$this->load->library('form_validation');

Works -
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('name', 'Name', 'trim|required');
```

You're calling a method of the class before the class is loaded.
This would also explain why autoloading the validation produced no error for you.

Comment: yeah, that's the only thing that makes sense here. It could also be because he's loading the library from the wrong method (although I doubt this). Like maybe he's loading it from the `index()` instead of the `__construct()` when he wanted to use it in several methods inside the controller class.

Comment: that would do it too. Maybe this will be the OP's first accepted answer... :-|

Comment: I am having the same issue as the OP and my code is in the correct order, looks like this:


`$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');`

results in the same issue, first: `A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Homepage::$form_validation

Filename: controllers/homepage.php

Line Number: 68`, then `Fatal error: Call to a member function set_rules() on a non-object in /Users/jzuckerman/Sites/ally/application/controllers/homepage.php on line 68`

Comment: Also I should add that i have reason to believe that CodeIgniter is finding my model correctly, as I can spawn a whole slew of different errors if I change the string passed to the load method and enter an invalid model name.

Comment: @Jon z - Try moving the validation to the __construct of your controller...`public function __construct() { parent::_construct(); $this->load->library('form_validation'); }`. That should remedy your error. Then pull up the CI User Guide -> Form Validation Class and compare your implementation to the example. You have to have something out of place for that particular error to display.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the Loader code, CodeIgniter gets the Controller instance to add the loaded objects to via the "get_instance" method.

In your sub-class of Controller, try also running that method and see what gets returned.

In my case I found that it was an autoloaded Controller sub-class that I was not even using or extending in any of my code - it was just a stub class for an idea I had to have all of my page controllers extend a base site controller, which in turns extended CI_Controller.  I stress that I was not extending this object but rather bypassing it for the CI_Controller in my own page controller.  I have no idea how CodeIgniter got the idea that I wanted to add my instances to that object, but anyway the fix was to remove that object from the autoload libraries list.

Crazy, but maybe it will work for you too.